# Использование библиотеки Jzy3d

Tags: java, maven, библиотеки, 3d, график

Всем привет!

Никак не могу разобраться с установкой сторонней библиотеки [Jzy3D](http://www.jzy3d.org/) для вывода всякого рода научных графиков и гистограмм на Java. На сайте почти нет никакой информации по установке либ, а с пониманием как настраивать Maven у меня всё очень плохо.

Кто-нибудь сможет разложить "по полочкам" как настроить Maven конкретно в этом случае (желательно в IntelliJ Idea)? Ну или посоветуйте альтернативную библиотеку/способ для вывода трехмерного графика по множеству точек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот тут](http://www.jzy3d.org/download-1.0.0.php)

Есть вот это:

```
Maven configuration

Maven dependency


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jzy3d</groupId>
    <artifactId>jzy3d-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

Jzy3d maven repository


<repositories>
  <repository>
     <id>jzy3d-snapshots</id>
     <name>Jzy3d Snapshots</name>
     <url>http://maven.jzy3d.org/snapshots</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
     <id>jzy3d-releases</id>
     <name>Jzy3d Releases</name>
     <url>http://maven.jzy3d.org/releases</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```